# Is kCLErrorNetwork a "fatal" error for Core Location?

Tags: iphone, core-location

Is kCLErrorNetwork "fatal", i.e. can location still be acquired or should we tell Core Location to stop updating the location?

In iOS 3.0, Core Location added an error code, kCLErrorNetwork. It is described as a "general, network-related error". Does this mean that neither the cell network nor Wi-Fi is available and Core Location can only use GPS? Or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell it to stop. It means that the http request to the lookup service failed either because the server returned an error, or there isn't a network connection.

You'll get similar errors when using NSURLConnection- refer to the NSError description for a more useful explanation of what went wrong.